# d3.js v4 - nodes are stuck in the top left corner

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I'm trying to create a webpage where users can select nodes (using select2) and each node that they select will be added to the network.
I'm currently failing to make the nodes appear in a place on the SVG other than the top left corner.

Here is my code on bl.ocks.org:
https://bl.ocks.org/shaief/2b4d5cfc7dcc0e03c59f0d6be3cc2913

I was looking to see what other people did, but i fail to find an answer that explains my issue.

EDIT:
It seems to me that although the code runs and ticks, in the 'ticked' function it doesn't influence the node objects. I can't figure out why though.

EDIT2:
I created a new file that is a copy-paste of Mike Bostock's Modifying a Force Layout II (https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/0adcc447925ffae87975a3a81628a196) and added my part of select2. The result is a log full of:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'vx' on string 'node-uuid-1234567890-5'
    at n (d3.v4.min.js:2)
    at d3.v4.min.js:2
    at be.each (d3.v4.min.js:2)
    at e (d3.v4.min.js:2)
    at n (d3.v4.min.js:2)
    at vn (d3.v4.min.js:2)
    at _n (d3.v4.min.js:2)
```

This is weird since Mike's example does use nodes IDs instead of ordinal indexes and i do not understand the cause.

EDIT3:
I'm adding the relevant code here, since i'm updating my gist with completely different code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>
  <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
  .container {
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: flex;
  }
  .controls {
    /* padding: 10px; */
    width: 350px;
  }
  #select-node-names {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .d3-container {
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
  .links line {
    stroke: #999;
    stroke-opacity: 0.6;
  }
  .nodes circle {
    stroke: #fff;
    /* stroke-width: 1.5px; */
    stroke-width: 0px;
  }
  text {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
    color: red;
    pointer-events: none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff;
  }
</style>
<div class='row'>
  <select id="select-node-names" multiple="multiple">
  </select>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="controls">
      <div class="test-nodes"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="d3-container">
        <svg width="960" height="600"></svg>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    d3.json("test.json", function(error, graph) {
      if (error) throw error;
      $("#select-node-names")
        .select2();
      var svg = d3.select("svg"),
        width = +svg.attr("width"),
        height = +svg.attr("height");
      // Color scale for node colors
      var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
      // Color scale for link colors
      var linkColor = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
      var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(graph.nodes)
        .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody()
          .strength(function(d) {
            return d.degree;
          }))
        .force('x', d3.forceX())
        .force('y', d3.forceY())
        .force("collision", d3.forceCollide(20))
        .force("centering", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
        .force("link", d3.forceLink()
          .id(function(d) {
            return d.id
          }))
        .on("tick", ticked);
      var nodes = [];
      var links = [];
      var nodeNames = Object.values(graph.nodes);
      var listItem = d3.select("#select-node-names")
        .selectAll("option")
        .data(nodeNames)
        .enter()
        .append("option")
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.object_name;
        })
        .attr("id", function(d) {
          return d.id;
        })
        .attr("value", function(d) {
          return d.id;
        });
      linksID = [];
      graph.links.forEach(function(e) {
        var sourceNode = graph.nodes[e.source]["id"];
        var targetNode = graph.nodes[e.target]["id"];
        linksID.push({
          source: sourceNode,
          target: targetNode,
          value: e.type
        });
      });
      $(document.body)
        .on("change", "#select-node-names", function() {
          nodes = search($("#select-node-names")
            .val(), "id", graph.nodes);
          nodesID = nodes.map(function(d) {
            return d.id;
          });
          linksSource = search(nodesID, "source", linksID);
          linksTarget = search(nodesID, "target", linksID);
          links = [];
          links = links.concat(linksSource, linksTarget);
          update();
        });
      var nodesG = svg.append("g");
      var linksG = svg.append("g");
      var node = nodesG
        .selectAll(".nodes")
      var link = linksG
        .selectAll(".links")
      update()
      function update() {
        var showSelectedNodes = d3.select(".test-nodes")
          .html("");
        var showSelectedNodes = d3.select(".test-nodes")
          .selectAll("myText")
          .data(nodes);
        showSelectedNodes.exit()
          .remove(); // EXIT
        showSelectedNodes.enter()
          .append("small") // ENTER
          .text(function(d) {
            return d.object_name + " // ";
          })
          .merge(showSelectedNodes) // ENTER + UPDATE
        var node = nodesG
          .selectAll("circle")
          .data(nodes);
        exitNode = node.exit()
          .remove(); // EXIT
        node = node.enter()
          .append("circle") // ENTER
          .attr("class", "nodes")
          .attr("r", 10)
          .attr("fill", function(d) {
            return color(d.node_type);
          })
          .append("title")
          .text(function(d) {
            return "Node: " + d.id + "\nName: " + d.object_name +
              "\nCoordinates: " + d.x + " - " + d.y;
          })
          .append("text")
          .attr("dx", 8)
          .attr("dy", ".31em")
          .text(function(d) {
            return d.object_name;
          })
          .call(d3.drag()
            .on("start", dragstarted)
            .on("drag", dragged)
            .on("end", dragended))
          .merge(node) // ENTER + UPDATE
        link = link.enter()
          .data(links)
          .append("line")
          .style('stroke', function(d) {
            return linkColor(d.type);
          })
          .attr("stroke-width", 2)
          .append("title")
          .text(function(d) {
            return "Source: " + d.source + "\nTarget: " + d.target +
              "\nType: " + d.type;
          });
        // Update and restart the simulation.
        simulation.nodes(nodes);
        simulation.force("link", d3.forceLink()
          .id(function(d) {
            return d.id
          }));
        simulation.alphaTarget(1);
        simulation.restart();
      }
      function ticked() {
        link
          .attr("x1", function(d) {
            return d.source.x;
          })
          .attr("y1", function(d) {
            return d.source.y;
          })
          .attr("x2", function(d) {
            return d.target.x;
          })
          .attr("y2", function(d) {
            return d.target.y;
          });
        node.attr("cx", function(d) {
            return d.x;
          })
          .attr("cy", function(d) {
            return d.y;
          })
          /* node.attr("transform", transform);*/
      }
      function dragstarted(d) {
        if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3)
          .restart();
        d.fx = null;
        d.fy = null;
      }
      function dragged(d) {
        d.fx = d3.event.x;
        d.fy = d3.event.y;
      }
      function dragended(d) {
        if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
        d.fx = null;
        d.fy = null;
      }
      function transform(d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
      };
    });
    function search(valuesArray, prop, myArray) {
      var res = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < valuesArray.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < myArray.length; j++) {
          if (myArray[j][prop] == valuesArray[i]) {
            res.push(myArray[j]);
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      return res
    }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The immediate things I see:

1. you're not adding your links to the simulation in all cases:  should be done through simulation.force("..").links(*link-array*)
2. you need to be clear on the id you're using for the links. you need to use ordinal position of the nodes e.g. 0 is first node. or the actual id of a node e.g "node-uuid-1234567890-1". You're trying for the latter. Read the [links.id api ref](https://github.com/d3/d3-force/blob/master/README.md#link_id) to pick which one you want to use. In your json, you use numbers for the link source and target.

To summarise these points, this should prob be your restart logic based on what youve done but you need to be consistent with your id usage:

```
  simulation.nodes(nodes);
  simulation.force("link").links(links);
  simulation.alpha(1).restart();
```

Have a look at Mike's [block for updating a force layout](http://blockbuilder.org/mbostock/0adcc447925ffae87975a3a81628a196) to be clear on how you update a simulation. You're doing too much work

Comment: Thanks! Just to clarify, this is a mocked JSON, but it has numbers for the source and target because it's going through Python's NetworkX.

Comment: Ok. So it seems to me that i followed the links.id API in my code - i referenced each link to the nodes by using their IDs instead of their indexes. When i changed it to the default behavior i get this: ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'vx' on string 'node-uuid-1234567890-2'
```

Comment: If you use a string id, you need to specify the link force like this:                                  var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))                                                                        such that your json link is: {source: "node-uuid-1234567890-1" target: "node-uuid-1234567890-2" value: 1} . The vx is the velocity x position, its basically saying, I cant figure out create this property to move your node/link

Comment: Thanks, but as you can see in my code, i already do that and it fails to do its magic in the tick part. Any idea why?

Comment: it will always fail if you dont add both the "source" node and "target" nodes together at the same time, coz it cant draw the link. that the biggest issue. your merge looks incorrect too, your enter/merge/remove is not done as it should be

Comment: And also you need to fix the links been added, you bind the data first, then through enter() to add. Changing this will at least add the links, but you still need to feed the simulation the right data:                                        link = linksG.selectAll(".links")
          .data(links)
          .enter()
          .append("line")